# How SElinux protects android from rooting

Tags: rooting, root-access, selinux

I know when rooting we execute a script and we use a *thing* that is already root and tell it to execute if it executes the script as root and then roots the phone so how does SElinux helps to protect against it

Example I exploited the kernel to execute the script as root it will executed in the kernel domain that is already root so it will the execute the script as root and give root privileges so how does SElinux protects against it?

Summary: *Exploit* is a any exploit in system to root
         *Script* script is a script that will be passed to exploited  area so                it can execute as root and root the system

So if i exploit it and pass the script how *SElinux* will protect against it?

Comment: what's the exploit? what's the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SELinux depends upon labels to match actions and policies. Labels determine what is allowed. Sockets, files, and processes all have labels in SELinux. SELinux decisions are based fundamentally on labels assigned to these objects and the policy defining how they may interact. In SELinux, a label takes the form: user:role:type:mls_level, where the type is the primary component of the access decisions, which may be modified by the other sections components which make up the label. The objects are mapped to classes and the different types of access for each class are represented by permissions.

The policy rules come in the form: allow domains types:classes permissions;, where:

Domain - A label for the process or set of processes. Also called a domain type as it is just a type for a process.
Type - A label for the object (e.g. file, socket) or set of objects.
Class - The kind of object (e.g. file, socket) being accessed.
Permission - The operation (e.g. read, write) being performed.
And so an example use of this would follow the structure:

> allow appdomain app_data_file:file rw_file_perms;

This says that all application domains are allowed to read and write files labeled app_data_file. Note that this rule relies upon macros defined in the global_macros file, and other helpful macros can also be found in the te_macros file, both of which can be found in the external/sepolicy directory in the AOSP source tree. Macros are provided for common groupings of classes, permissions and rules, and should be used whenever possible to help reduce the likelihood of failures due to denials on related permissions.

In addition to individually listing domains or types in a rule, one can also refer to a set of domains or types via an attribute. An attribute is simply a name for a set of domains or types. Each domain or type can be associated with any number of attributes. When a rule is written that specifies an attribute name, that name is automatically expanded to the list of domains or types associated with the attribute. For example, the domain attribute is associated with all process domains, and the file_type attribute is associated with all file types.

Use the syntax above to create avc rules that comprise the essence of an SELinux policy. A rule takes the form:

```
<rule variant> <source_types> <target_types> : <classes> <permissions>
```

The rule indicates what should happen when a subject labeled with any of the source_types attempts an action corresponding to any of the permissions on an object with any of the class classes which has any of the target_types label. The most common example of one of these rules is an allow rule, e.g.:

> allow domain null_device:chr_file { open };

This rule allows a process with any domain associated with the ‘domain’ attribute to take the action described by the permission ‘open’ on an object of class ‘chr_file’ (character device file) that has the target_type label of ‘null_device.’ In practice, this rule may be extended to include other permissions:

> allow domain null_device:chr_file { getattr open read ioctl lock
>   append write};

When combined with the knowledge that ‘domain’ is an attribute assigned to all process domains and that null_device is the label for the character device /dev/null, this rule basically permits reading and writing to /dev/null.

A domain generally corresponds to a process and will have a label associated with it.

For example, a typical Android app is running in its own process and has the label of untrusted_app that grants it certain restricted permissions.

Platform apps built into the system run under a separate label and are granted a distinct set of permissions. System UID apps that are part of the core Android system run under the system_app label for yet another set of privileges.

Access to the following generic labels should never be directly allowed to domains; instead, a more specific type should be created for the object or objects:

socket_device
device
block_device
default_service
system_data_file
tmpfs

**Source: [SELinux concepts](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/selinux/concepts.html)

For more details, see: [Security-Enhanced Linux in Android](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/selinux/index.html#supporting_documentation) 

[Implementing SELinux](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/selinux/implement.html)**

Comment: So if I request kernel to execute the script it will be executed by the kernel and it has root privileges so it will be executed as root and then the phone will be rooted

Comment: u gave lot info in answer but didn't answer my question

Comment: Actually, you were able to execute that script because that was an exploit script, not a simple "Hello World1" Script ;)  
Exploits use the loopholes in code and do their dirty job :)  
Don't confuse yourself

Comment: So what's the pont

Comment: So what's the point for SElinux

Comment: It just means that the SELinux is not implemented properly by the ROM maker (yeah, even Google sometimes) :)

Comment: That's why different phones use different exploits to root